# How to Sortby Multiple Colums - Linq to SQL

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

Wanting to sortby x.IRNumber - .thenby x.BedLocation but no luck could someone help me in the right direction?

Thanks

Mark

string jobID = ddlJobID.SelectedValue;

```
        using (rw_forms context = new rw_forms())
        {
            var result = from c in context.hospedia_running_sheet_view.Select(x => new
            {
                x.uniqueID,
                x.irNumber,
                x.ward,
                x.bed_location,
                x.bed_extension,
                x.select_technology,
                x.select_fitting_of_pattress,
                x.select_fitting_of_backplate,
                x.fixing_method_used,
                x.id,
                x.status,
                x.latitude,
                x.longitude,
                x.accuracy,
                x.createdAt,
                x.createdByName,
                x.fixing,
                x.statusID,
                x.commissioningID,
                x.jobID,
                x.siteName
            }).Where(x=> x.statusID == 1).Where(x => x.jobID == ((jobID == "-1") ? x.jobID : jobID)).OrderByDescending(x => x.irNumber) select c;

            grdForms.DataSource = result.ToList();
            grdForms.DataBind();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: No luck isn't very helpful. What does it do when you try it. I'm assuming you are trying `.OrderByDescending(x => x.irNumber).ThenBy(x=>x.BedLocation)`

Comment: Hi, apologies yes not helpful this and yes this is what im getting in return as above,  CS1061: 'AnonymousType#1' does not contain a definition for 'BedLocation' and no extension method 'BedLocation' accepting a first argument of type 'AnonymousType#1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Looks like you should be using `x.bed_location` rather than `x.BedLocation`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something like this

```
SELECT * FROM TEST
ORDER BY TEST.ID,TEST.RID DESC
```

-

```
from t in db.TEST 
orderby t.ID, t.RID descending 
select t
```